# How can i pass a pointer of an int inside a function to another function and manipulate there the in as well?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testFunction(int *a){
    printf("In a should be 5: %d", *a);
    *a = 0;
    printf("In a should be 0: %d", *a);
    test2Function(&a);
}

void test2Function(int *a){
    printf("In F2 a should be 0: %d", *a);
    *a = 2;
    printf("In F2 a should be 2: %d", *a);
}

int main(){

    int a = 5;
    testFunction(&a);
    printf("In main() a should be 2: %d", a);


    return 0;
}
```

How can i send the pointer from a given to a function inside a function to another function?
So that the statements inside the code above are all true

Current output is:

```
In a should be 5: 5
In a should be 0: 0
In F2 a should be 0: 6422316
In F2 a should be 2: 2
In main() a should be 2: 0
```

Comment: Please note that your code won't compile properly because you use `test2Function` in `testFunction`. You need to either place a prototype of `test2Function` above `testFunction` or move it all together up.

Comment: @machine_1 Thank you for the information. Well completly forgott about that. The code actually compiles also on my current project. I just got a few warnings which i want to resolve at the end of my project. Now with your hint i was able to resolve them now.

Comment: You are using the variable `a` to mean different things in different functions.  In `main`, it's an `int`.  In the other functions, it's an `int *`.  So in main you correctly take its address to convert it to an `int *`.  But in `testFunction`, it's already a pointer, so taking its address produces an `int **`.  Just pass it straight through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
test2Function(&a);
```

Do:

```
test2Function(a);
```

Because you simply want to copy the pointer you already have, not take the address of the pointer itself.